# How to center an image in vue.js?

Tags: html, css, image, vue.js

I'm trying to do a front of an HTML website by using vue.js,
but I wasn't able to center an image using css.

I wrote all of my code in the App.vue file :

```
<template>
  <div id="container3">
    <img id="teamBackground" src="./assets/bourg_palette_rounded.png" alt="Bourg palette in background" width="360" height="170"/>
  </div>
</template>

<style>
<!-- team -->
#container3 img{
  display:block;
  margin:0 auto;
}
</style>
```

I tried the `text-align` and the `display-block` + `margin: 0 auto` properties but it didn't change neither the placement of the image or the placement of other elements

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using display:flex; together with justify-content:center;?
You can also try out using position:absolute;

You can read more about image-centering methods here: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-center-an-image-in-css/

Answer (score 1):

```
#container3 {
    display: flex;
    width:100%;
    height:500px; 
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Flexbox is the most suitable solution for your problem.
The parent (#container3) should be a flex  container. For horizontal centering we use justify-content: center & for vertical centering we use align-items: center.

Note: We must provide height to the parent for child to align in vertical direction. Also the above example is for default flex-direction ( row). For more details refer to the page https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/css-centering-using-flexbox

Answer (score 0):

```css
#container3 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

you can put those css codes to the parent div